# Call a executable to execute command in all folders cmd or powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am using this .bat command to my tool.
rip_images.exe is a tool to merge images

```
rip_images.exe -c 1 00000001.jpg 00000002.jpg 00000003.jpg 00000004.jpg -o out.png
rip_images.exe -c 1 00000001.bmp 00000002.bmp 00000003.bmp 00000004.bmp -o out.bmp
```

just work if i put these files in the same folder of the executable.

i need a command that search for .jpg and bmp in folders and execute the .exe in each folder, give the merged files in each folder separetely.
cmd or powershell.
I have try something like that in powershell

```
Powershell "Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *bmp |ForEach-Object 
{.\rip_image.exe -c 1 $_.FullName}"
```

but it do in file by file, need something like save variables to put in arguments
maybe for /r?

example:

```
 rip_images.exe -c 1 var1 var2 var3 var4 -o out.bmp
```

thank you for attention.

Comment: Are you calling powershell from CMD? If so, any particular reason to not run the code directly from powershell?

Comment: yes, just to make more easier for the users, just click in .bat, instead open powershell.

about my question.
Have two ways doing by cmd command or powershell,, maybe do a for to storage the variables, i am not familarized with basic commands, so i am asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it using exclusively PowerShell, if you attempt to run this from CMD by calling `powershell.exe` this will most likely fail. You can however store this as a `.ps1` file and the use `powershell -File path\to\script.ps1`.

You can use `Group-Object` to group the files by their extension and then pass the `FullName` of that group of objects to your binary:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_ -File |
        Where-Object { $_.Extension -in '.bmp', '.png' } |
        Group-Object Extension | ForEach-Object {
            # $_.Name is the extension here
            $folderName = $_.Group.Directory[0]
            .\rip_image.exe -c 1 $_.Group.FullName -o "$folderName out$($_.Name)"
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but its merged all files in one.
i need to merged the files for each folder
example, inside data folder have 3 folders A B C, in each folder have 4 pics, this scripts is taking 4(A)+4(B)+4(C) pics and merge in one, but i need merge 4 pics of each folder to one for folder, so it will be 3 merged pics.

Comment: @ThiagoMartinsdossantos I see, in that case, the update might work. First you get the directories and then for each directory you get the files and merge them

Comment: almost there, sorry to bother you again.
as per outfile have the same name, the script frozen.
can we take the name of folder plus .$_name? example Folder1./bmp/png, folder2.png or instead the output file go to the main folder, go to the same folder of each pictures ?

Comment: @ThiagoMartinsdossantos I guess that should work, check the update